# How to check trained neural net accuracy after testing it?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I trained a neural network with an Input matrix of 792x4415 and a target of 80x4415.

```
net = patternnet(10);
[net,tr] = train(net,Input,target);
```

After training, I tested it with a test matrix of size 792x204

```
result = sim(net,Test);
```

I get a 80x204 result matrix. Now one way is to see the matrix manually and to see for each image for which class out of 80, it has the highest number.
But how can I calculate the accuracy in terms of number of correctly/incorrectly classified classes for this test matrix?

I tried using

```
[c,cm] = confusion(target,result);
fprintf('Percentage Correct Classification for Unknown Data   : %f%%\n', 100*(1-c));
fprintf('Percentage Incorrect Classification for Unknown  : %f%%\n', 100*c);
```

But I get the following error

```
Targets and outputs have different dimensions.
```

I know the test matrix has 204 examples instead of 4415, that's why I get the error but I dont have that many test examples to test the model with. Is there a way with which I can use confusion function or any other function to calculate the accuracy using this test matrix?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to do character recognition. I have 80 characters in total and the total number of image examples for all the characters are 4415, hence my Input and target matrices are of size 792x4415 and 80x4415 respectively. After the training is done, I'm using 204 test images and my test matrix is of size 792x204.

Comment: Need more clarity on the question. What are your training and testing datasets exactly. What information do they represent. Moreover, it does not matter if the number of instances in the training and the testing dataset are different.

Comment: @aditya..I'm trying to do character recognition. I have 80 characters in total and the total number of image examples for all the characters are 4415, hence my Input and target matrices are of size 792x4415 and 80x4415 respectively. After the training is done, I'm using 204 test images and my test matrix is of size 792x204.

Comment: You don't need to call `confusion` with the `target` from the training, but with the targets from testing - which should be 80x204.

Comment: @hbaderts Okay so in my text matrix..out of 80, I have got test samples for only 23 classes. Also the output matrix I get after testing is of size 80x204. Wouldn't it classify wrong if I make a testTarget of size 80x204 and label it for 23 classes and leave the rows from 24-80 as zero? I get the correct classification as 0.980392%.

Comment: Well, for your test to be really representative, you should have test samples for all 80 classes. If you don't have any test data for one class, then you simply don't know how well this class performs. I'd suggest taking a bit more samples for testing and less for training. E.g. 80% / 20%, i.e. about 400 or 500 test samples.

Comment: @ hbaderts okay i wanted to ask one thing more, suppose in the original target matrix used for training i had a character in the first row and its training samples ranged from 1-13 columns..and now in the test matrix used for testing, I had the same test sample character in the 1st row and its test samples ranged from 1-5 columns, or suppose if I had the same character in the 8th row and it ranged from 1-5 columns, would the placement matter w.r.t the original test matrix used for training? or would both of the cases I described produce accurate result?